# How to iterate through a struct in go with reflect

Tags: reflection, struct, go

I have a specific struct that contains some url parameters, I want to build a url parameters string using reflect to iterate through the struct field, so that I wont care about what's the struct really contains.

Let's say I have a struct like this:

```
type Student struct {
   Name string `paramName: "username"`
   Age int `paramName: userage`
}
```

And I assign a student like this:

```
s := Student{
  Name : "Bob",
  Age : 15,
}
```

I want to build a query parameter string like this for this student instance:

```
username=Bob&userage=15
```

So far I have got:

```
func (s Student) buildParams() string {
    st := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    fieldCount := st.NumField()
    params := ""
    for i := fieldCount; i > 0 ; i-- {
      params = params +  "&" + st.Field(i).Tag.Get("paramName") + "=" + st.Field(i).Name
    }
    return params
}
```

But `s.buildParams()` gets me nothing, not event the tag value of paramName in each field :-(

So How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a space between the colon and the value in the struct tags. `paramName:"username"` not `paramName: "username"`. Also, you're using the field name instead of the field value. In order to turn the value into a string you'll need something a bit more complex. Here is a complete example: http://play.golang.org/p/4hEQ4jgDph

Comment: Or simplifying by just using `fmt.Sprint` (and supporting all types that can be "stringified"): http://play.golang.org/p/PKfcuGk-cO